How to determine model changes?
My QListView class is feed by QAbstractListModel, where I've implemented insert, remove, update rows. There is no problem between model and list view. However, I would like to subscribe to model change to do some custom calculations.
For that I can't find any events neither in QListView nor in QAbstractListModel, to which I can connect and receive signal something like onDataChanged.
Below is a sample code to demonstrate details.
class WorktimeListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    ...
        def addItem(self, data):
            index = QModelIndex()
            self.beginInsertRows(index, self.rowCount(index), self.rowCount(index))
            ...
            self.endInsertRows()

        def modifyItem(self, index, data):
            self.beginResetModel()
            ...
            self.endResetModel()

Somewhere in main window class:
...
self.customWorktimesModel = WorktimeListModel()
self.listViewWorktimes.setModel(self.customWorktimesModel)
# I need something like this
self.listViewWorktimes.onModelChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)
# or this
self.customWorktimesModel.onModelChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)

...
def updateLabel(self):
    value = self.customWorktimesModel.calculate_something()
    self.label.setText(value)


provide some code please.

@Mohammedalmalki done

QAbstractListModel inherits a whole bunch of signals from QAbstractItemModel that can be used to react on changes in the model.

@mahkitah Could you please bring one example on how to intercept dataChanged in context of my example code?

The two examples from the model can be detected with rowsInserted and modelReset signals.

DataChanged has to be emitted by the model when the data changes. You have to implement that yourself.

@mahkitah In my model class I added self.modelReset.emit(). In my main window class I am trying to connect to this signal like this: self.customWorktimesModel.modelReset.connect(...). However this doesn't work.

You don't have to emit modelReset explicitly. It is emitted when endResetModel() is called and you already do that.

@mahkitah If you would like put it all as an answer and I will accept it. thx

Using the begin/endResetModel when updating an item is completely inappropriate and wrong. You're not resetting the model, you're updating one item. Emit dataChanged explicitly in modifyItem, or eventually override setData() appropriately (which also implies emitting dataChanged anyway) and use that instead. I strongly urge you to take your time to carefully read the whole QAbstractItemModel class documentation and the full model/view programming guide, it's very important that you always use the appropriate functions and signals.

You can use the dataChanged signal from QAbstractItemModel.
...
self.customWorktimesModel = WorktimeListModel()
self.listViewWorktimes.setModel(self.customWorktimesModel)

# connect to the signal
self.customWorktimesModel.dataChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)

...

def updateLabel(self, topLeft, bottomRight, roles=None):
    value = self.customWorktimesModel.calculate_something()
    self.label.setText(value)


Take note that you need to update updateLabel()'s parameters.

Well, here I have to subclass QListView. I was hoping to use the signals/slots provided by QListView and QAbstractListModel. Please see my updated question.

There is actually a dataChanged signal in QAbstractListModel which it inherits from QAbstractItemModel. Would this be sufficient for your use case?

If you could also tell how I can "listen" to this signal then it might be sufficient. I've tried self.customWorktimesModel.modelReset.connect(...) which is another signal but will serve the purpose as well. Looks like I have problem "connecting".

Modified the answer to cater to you updateLabel function.

This is pointless and wrong. First of all, the dataChanged function is called automatically when the model emits dataChanged, so overriding the function to emit a further signal is a bit pointless: just connect to the dataChanged signal of the model: self.customWorktimesModel.dataChanged.connect(self.updateLabel). Then, the signal emission syntax is wrong: signals become real signals when bound to an instance, so using class.signal.emit() is wrong and will raise an exception. The correct syntax should be self.onDataChanged.emit(), but, as noted above, it's pointless.

Modified the answer to use model's dataChanged signal instead.
